# Why does boost::find_first take a non-const reference to its input?

Tags: c++, string, boost

Boost's [`find_first`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/find_first.html) algorithm is a souped-up equivalent of C's `strstr()`, but why does the haystack — the search space — get passed in as a **non-const** reference? The matching range is returned in a separate `iterator_range` object, so it's not a matter of output-by-reference.

It prevents invocation with a temporary range created by [make_iterator_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html).

```
const std::string str("haystack");
const std::string findstr("stack");

boost::sub_range<const std::string> match = boost::algorithm::find_first(
        boost::make_iterator_range(str),
        boost::make_iterator_range(findstr));
```

Instead, a local variable representing the source range must be created explicitly:

```
const std::string str("haystack");
const std::string findstr("stack");

boost::sub_range<const std::string> haystack = boost::make_iterator_range(str);

boost::sub_range<const std::string> match = boost::algorithm::find_first(
        haystack,
        boost::make_iterator_range(findstr));
```

(This applies equally to the other functions in [boost/algorithm/string/find.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.find_hpp), ie. `find`, `ifind_first`, `find_last`, `ifind_last`, `find_nth`, `ifind_nth`, `find_head`, `find_tail` & `find_token`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's to ensure that the returned range is still valid after the call to `find_first`.

While the initial case above would be fine, the following would result in a `match` that points to a destroyed temporary string:

```
boost::sub_range<const std::string> match = boost::algorithm::find_first(
        boost::make_iterator_range(std::string("haystack"),
        boost::make_iterator_range(std::string("stack"));
```

The requirement that the haystack be non-const prevents it binding to a temporary object (rvalue) which is destroyed upon `find_first`'s return and invalidates the `match`'s iterators.

Comment: This is really a poor reason. While it solves this potential undefined behavior, it also inhibits potential uses where you get just a const reference and might need to search inside it.

Comment: With C++11 the rvalue-binding could be prevented while allowing pass-by-const-ref, but I suspect this method was chosen for its broad compatibility. It doesn't entirely inhibit the case you mention - searching inside a const reference - it just requires the caller to create a non-const `iterator_range` with `const_iterator` template parameter to "prove" that the iterated object has a sufficient lifetime. It's not ideal, and I think I'd prefer the ability to shoot myself in the foot, but at least I understand why it was written this way.

Comment: I've seen the opposite design decision (accepting temporaries) bite people a couple times, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565375/what-is-prefered-way-of-passing-pointer-reference-to-existing-object-in-a-constr) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991964/constraints-on-the-lifetime-of-the-argument-to-stdregex-match-and-stdregex) for example. Whichever way you choose, it would nice if they would document this stuff.