# How do I create a const boost::iterator_range

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, constants, const-iterator

The comment at [Why does boost::find_first take a non-const reference to its input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500163/why-does-boostfind-first-take-a-non-const-reference-to-its-input#comment18477636_13500243) suggests "the caller to create a non-const iterator_range with const_iterator template parameter to "prove" that the iterated object has a sufficient lifetime."

What does this mean and how do I do it?

In particular, how do I achieve const-correctness with this code?

```
typedef std::map<int, double> tMyMap;
tMyMap::const_iterator subrange_begin = my_map.lower_bound(123);
tMyMap::const_iterator subrange_end = my_map.upper_bound(456);

// I'd like to return a subrange that can't modify my_map
// but this vomits template errors complaining about const_iterators
return boost::iterator_range<tMyMap::const_iterator>(subrange_begin, subrange_end);
```

Comment: Compiles for me using [gcc 5.3 and Boost 1.59 on CoLiRu](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bd88699b279a77a).

Comment: Weird, maybe it's a version issue. I'm gcc 4.8.4 / Boost 1.55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having non-const references *to the range* avoids binding to temporaries ¹

I'd avoid your conundrum² by letting the compiler do your work:

```
tMyMap const& my_map; // NOTE const
// ...

return boost::make_iterator_range(my_map.lower_bound(123), mymap.upper_bound(456));
```

---

¹ Standard C++ extends lifetimes of temporaries bound to const-reference variables, but this doesn't apply to references bound to object members. Therefore, aggregating ranges by reference is very prone to this mistake.

/OT: IMO even *with* the precautions/checks some Boost Range features (like adaptors) are frequently too unsafe to use; I've fallen into those traps more often than I care to admit.

² apart from the fact that [we cannot reproduce it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365241/how-do-i-create-a-const-boostiterator-range/36370974#comment60355153_36365241) from the sample you gave